# Avoid bypassing maxlength attribute using jQuery

Tags: jquery, textarea, maxlength

I'm having trouble trying to validate a user bypassing the maxlength value in a textarea field but it seems none of my validations work. I'm trying to validate is a user can change the maxlength above our initial limit or if the maxlength is removed from the element.

It's kinda easy to do that but some users seem to be doing it.

Here's my code:

```
<form class="forms" action="/checkout" name="ordersubmit" id="shipping" method="post" novalidate="">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-11 noPadding">
        <label class="InstructionsBlock" for="Instructions">
            Instructions
        </label>
        <textarea id="Instructions" name="Instructions" maxlength="62" rows="6" cols="50">
        </textarea>
</div>
</form>

    var instructions = $("#Instructions");
    $("form").submit() {
        if (instructions.val(instructions.attr("maxlength")) > 70 || instructions.length) {
        alert("Please limit your instruction to a maximum of 70 characters");
    }
}
```

When the form is submitted it doesn't validate and the solution might be easier than I thought but I can't seem to make this work.

Comment: it's unclear to me what you're trying to check with this: if (instructions.val($(this).attr("maxlength")) > 70 || instructions.length)

Comment: I've edited my code with the html also

Comment: I have edited my answer to be more applicable to your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always do server side validation. And I don't see the rest of your code, so I don't know what $(this) is. But here's a simple example of what I think you are trying to check.

```js
const $instructions = $("#Instructions");
const max = 70;  // for testing; change to 70 or whatever for yours

// check the attribute is present and less than our max and that the value doesn't exceed it
$("form").on("submit", () => {
  let maxlength = parseInt($instructions.attr("maxlength"));
  if (!$instructions.attr("maxlength") ||
      $instructions.attr("maxlength") > max ||
      $instructions.val().length > maxlength) {
        alert(`Please limit your instruction to a maximum of ${max} characters`); // this should really be in a nice error div or something
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
   else {
   alert("good");
   return false; // return true for actual submit, or omit this else entirely
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="forms" action="/checkout" name="ordersubmit" id="shipping" method="post" novalidate="">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-11 noPadding">
        <label class="InstructionsBlock" for="Instructions">
            Instructions
        </label>
        <textarea id="Instructions" name="Instructions" maxlength="62" rows="6" cols="50">
        </textarea>
     <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to set the validations correctly based on your code.